# Can I Specify Custom Naming Style in Resharper Command Line Tool?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm aware that I can define my own naming style in the Resharper UI, but I would like to know if this is possible on the Resharper CLT, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Use the UI to define the naming style and save it to a settings file, CLT will use the same settings. Alternatively, define your naming style through an .editorconfig file (see the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html#use-editorconfig-to-configure-naming-rules)).